# Get a substring from a string using a wildcard in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like `/test/file/sometext/public/image` and a second string `/test1/file/sometext1/public/image1`.

I want to get the substring starting from `file` and ending on `public`.

So the first string should return `file/sometext/public/` and from the 2nd string it should return `file/sometext1/public/`.

In every string this `file` and `public` is static.

How will I do this in javascript?

Basically I need this

```
str = '/test/file/sometext/public/image';
var str1 = str.replace("file/sometext/public/", "");
```

But I need here a wildcard so that sometext can be replaces whatever text comes between `file` and `public`. Hope you get my point.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: For greater flexibility, always use regular expressions, and a capturing group, in case you might extend your requirements in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Regular Expression.

```js
var str = '/test/file/sometext/public/image';

var reg = /file\/[^\/]*\/public/i;
var replace = str.replace(reg, 'something');

console.log('before',str);
console.log('after',replace);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler and doing the same thing in this case?? `file\/.*\/public/i` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** to splits a string into an array of strings, with **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/slice)** that returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object and finally the **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** to joins all elements of an array into a final string :

```js
var parts = '/test/file/sometext/public/image'.split('/');

console.log( parts.slice(2, 5).join('/') );
```

Answer (score 0):

If all strings follow the same folder structure you can split them in to an array and rebuild it with the required parts, like this:

```js
var arr = str = '/test/file/sometext/public/image'.split('/');
var str1 = arr[2] + '/' + arr[3] + '/' + arr[4] + '/';
console.log(str1);
```